# Replace the first word in a line with a word from the previous line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have text like this

```
replace: c
       1: USA
-
replace: SN
       1: Garlapati
```

For each line starting with `replace:` I would like to use the following word to replace the *first word* on the next line (which is `1` in this case):

```
replace: c
c: USA
-
replace: SN
SN: Garlapati
```

Comment: Please help me understand what this means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line should do:

```
awk -F': *' -v OFS=": " '$1=="replace"{r=$2;print;next}r{$1=r;r=""}7' file
```

test with your input:

```
kent$  cat f
replace: c
       1: USA
-
replace: SN
       1: Garlapati

kent$  awk -F': *' -v OFS=": " '$1=="replace"{r=$2;print;next}r{$1=r;r=""}7' f
replace: c
c: USA
-
replace: SN
SN: Garlapati
```

Comment: Hi Kent, 

How can i delete the two consecutive lines which starts with same word ...

Example:  

uniqueMember
replace:
add:
uniqueMember: 
replace:
replace:

My output should be 

uniqueMember
replace:
add:
uniqueMember: